# change bar colour in plotly animation chart

Tags: python, animation, colors, plotly, bar-chart

I've plotted an animated bar chart using the following code, but the default bar colour is blue, how can I change it?

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, x="x", y="Y", 
  animation_frame="Year_slider")

fig.show()
```

I've tried:

```
fig.update_traces(marker_color='green')
```

This only provide the green colour for the first bar, not the rest of the bars as the year slider goes further, how could I make all the bar colour green instead of the default colour?

Answer (score 0):

Animation in plotly is realized by creating data for each frame of the animation, which can be seen by executing `print(fig.frames)`. The composition of the graph consists of the initial graph data(`fig.data`), layout information(`fig.layout`), and animation frame information(`fig.frames`). So not only the initial color needs to be changed, but also the animation frames. For each frame, change the color of the bar graph. Your data is unknown, but I have created the code by modifying the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/) in the reference for illustrative purposes.

```
import plotly.express as px

data_Africa = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Africa'")
fig = px.bar(data_Africa, x='country', y='pop', animation_frame='year')
fig.update_traces(marker_color='green')

for i,frame in enumerate(fig.frames):
    fig.frames[i]['data'][0]['marker']['color'] = 'green'

fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 100_000_000])

fig.show()
```

[image]